# How to supply user arguments for a script invoked via Custom Ribbon from within Excel?

Tags: excel, openpyxl, xlwings

I have a python script that needs to run on my linux server with some arguments:
e.g.

```
python testprogram.py --arg1=abc --arg2==xyz
```

I have a custom Ribbon implemented in my Excel file (on windows desktop client). How can I implement some kind of pop-up so that when I click on the ribbon, it launches the pop-up to allow the user to specify input arguments arg 1 & arg2 and then invoke the python script that can run remotely on the linux server? I need to accomplish this while leaving the excel workbook open, hence I am using the custom ribbon. Not sure if there is a better way to do this.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set it up such that when you click on a button in the ribbon, a userform appears (google how to trigger a userform)(will need to trigger this userform with an event...like a button click). Then, on the userform, put a couple input boxes and a button. Add code for the userform such that on the button_click(), the program will collect the user input and call the python program w those arguments (google how to call python program from excel VBA)